# Table alias not working with join

Tags: mysql

I get error `Unknown column 'sch1.laestab' in 'field list'` on this query

```
SELECT
    sch1.laestab AS eef_sch_id,
    sch1.sch_name AS sch_name,
    sch1.urn AS sch_dfe,
    foo1.*
FROM tbl_Schools as sch1
JOIN (
    SELECT
    sch2.laestab AS eef_sch2_id,
    sch2.sch_name AS sch2_name,
    sch2.urn AS sch2_dfe
    FROM tbl_SimilarSchools ss2
    JOIN tbl_Schools sch2 ON sch2.laestab = ss2.cluster_id
    WHERE cluster_id = sch1.laestab
    AND cluster_id != school_id
    AND sch2.use_KS4 = '1'
    ORDER BY distance2 ASC
    LIMIT 1
) as foo1
```

But works fine if I remove `JOIN` part. What is wrong with my syntaxis?

Comment: Add `on 1=1` at and of your query. `JOIN` statement need `ON` statement.

Comment: @Evgeny better use `CROSS JOIN` keyword instead ?

Comment: I think there is no difference

Comment: haven't helped ON and CROSS JOIN

Comment: Ah, now I see, I need to use alias within JOIN, that part generates error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo inside JOIN here:

```
WHERE cluster_id = sch1.laestab
```

Should be

```
WHERE cluster_id = sch2.laestab
```

Or if this is not typo, then you should move out this check outside join into 'ON' section. Something like this

```
JOIN (
    SELECT
    cluster_id,
    sch2.laestab AS eef_sch2_id,
    sch2.sch_name AS sch2_name,
    sch2.urn AS sch2_dfe
    FROM tbl_SimilarSchools ss2
    JOIN tbl_Schools sch2 ON sch2.laestab = ss2.cluster_id
    WHERE cluster_id != school_id
    AND sch2.use_KS4 = '1'
    ORDER BY distance2 ASC
    LIMIT 1
) as foo1
on foo1.cluster_id = sch1.laestab
```

Comment: isn't typo, need laestab from the sch1

Comment: Then move this check into `on` section like I said.

Comment: He's right "sch1" doesn't exist in the context where you call `WHERE cluster_id = sch1.laestab`